# Sending a Restangular DELETE or customDELETE with a body

Tags: rest, angularjs, restangular

when I hit the api with:

how can I hit the api (not from the angular app) with:

apiadress/endpoint/idnumber/?param=param

with a DELETE, everything works fine and as expected.
but When I do so from Restangular like this:

```
Restangular.one("endpoint").customDELETE(idnumber,params)
```

I get this response from the server:

"detail": "Unsupported media type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' in request."

looks like the DELETE is coming with a BODY to the server, and I can't find how to force an empty body.

(I saw this in other questions so I'll say that in advance, yes the api is in a different port in my dev machine, and I have :

```
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
    ])
```

I like Restangular, but this problem keeps biting me. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the content type, not that there is no body in the request. (At least I read that from your question.)

Try to define a default content type header, that should be used by Restangular as well:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

Answer (score 9):

Try This out.

```
var restMyService = Restangular.all("MyService");
restMyService.customDELETE("myPath",{pramOne: $scope.pramOne},
                            {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                             idnumber)
                          .then(function(res){
                               //To DO - Success
                           }, 
                           function errorCallback() {
                               //TODO Error Handle
                           } 
                          );
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add request payload with customDelete you should use this:

```
Restangular.all('path').customDELETE('', {}, {}, payloadObject);
```

*this will not add payload parameters to URL, this method add payload object to body.